# Wagtail + Django problem - page is redirecting to wagtail although the url is not for the wagtail page

Tags: python, html, django, wagtail

```
url(r'^$', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='homepage'),

class HomePage(RedirectView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('check')
        return render(request, url)
```

And this is the html:

```
<a href="{% url 'public_portal:homepage' %}">
```

although, I get a page with full design of wagtail Page model I have.
Anyone knows why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you don't have Wagtail urls properly namespaced they will overwrite your site urls. The documentation recommends to place them under a path such as `/pages/`.

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html#url-configuration